# OS independent access to variables in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, environment-variables, package.json

To access a variable in npm scripts you would do something like this in your `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "preinstall": "echo ${npm_package_name}"
}
```

The problem is that works only in Unix, not Windows, where you have to use `%npm_package_name%`.

Is there a way to do this OS independent? It will be good if npm could do such a variable expansion, before invoking the command.

Comment: What good does accessing environment variables do here?  Can I get access to them in other parts of package.json, such as in the dependencies section?

Comment: Note that `${npm_package_name}` can be simply written `$npm_package_name` without { }

Comment: @tanguy_k please read my entire post. The problem is that it doesn't work on Windows.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To make it cross-platform, use [`cross-var`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-var):

```
"scripts": {
    "preinstall": "cross-var echo ${npm_package_name}"
}
```

Comment: cross-var must be installed already in node_modules for preinstall to work

Comment: Is this still the preferred solution?

Comment: I recommend an actively maintained library: [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env)

Answer (score 3):

There's no known way to do this that's OS independent.

A good workaround is to execute the command within a node script:

First, change the `preinstall` command to execute a node script:

```
"scripts": {
    "preinstall": "node nameEcho.js"
}
```

Then you define the command in the **nameEcho.js** file:

```
// require the package.json file
var pjson = require('./package.json');

// echo the package's name
console.log(pjson.name);
```