# In package.json, can I somehow use an environment variable to construct a Git URL for a dependency?

Tags: node.js, git, npm

For a Node application, I have modules dependencies which are hosted by the usual npm registry, but I also have a module dependency hosted in my privately run git server.  The below works fine for me (as the auth is taken care of by a token in `~/.npmrc`), but is there a way for the `package.json` to recognize an environment variable so it will work for all *user*s/developers on my team? My main motivation is I don't want to tgz the custom module, as I want to always be pulling the latest version of it, and there are many modules that depend on this custom module.

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "my-custom-module": "git+https://joe.smith@ourcompany.com/scm/repo1/my-custom-module.git",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.235.1",
```

ideally takes the form of something like this?  Or other similar mechanism?

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "my-custom-module": "git+https://${%USER}@ourcompany.com/scm/repo1/my-custom-module.git",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.235.1",
```

Comment: Hope it helps-  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36260436/access-environment-variable-in-package-json

Comment: This doesn't answer your question at all, so I'm leaving it as a comment instead, but if you skip the username, it should still work as long as you have set up your git config correctly.

Comment: @isherwood, yes the mechanism was what I was looking for.  But appreciably different question because it's a npm dependency vs. CLI script, and Ian's response ultimately solved my issue?  Happy to hit 'That solved my problem' otherwise.