# Is it possible to execute package options without having to explicitly declare them in package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm not sure with the exact term to describe my issue but what I want is for my credentials to not be exposed in `package.json`, like for example, this package usage instruction:

```
node ./app.js | pino-mongodb [options]
```

so in my `package.json`, if I implement it, it will be like:

```
"start": 'node ./app.js | pino-mongodb --username=myUser --password=myPw'
```

How do you handle packages like this without having the credentials exposed in your git repository?

Thanks for the advice.

Sample package: https://github.com/pinojs/pino-mongodb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use environment variables, like this:

*package.json*

```
"start": "node ./app.js | pino-mongodb --username=${USERNAME} --password=${PASSWORD}"
```

Call it from the command line after the environment variables have been set. A simple way to do it:

```
USERNAME=johndoe PASSWORD=secret666 npm run start
```

**Note**: this works fine in MacOS and Linux, [for Windows, see related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36260436/access-environment-variable-in-package-json).

If your environment variables are stored in a `.env` file, you can read them with the `source` command, like this:

*package.json*

```
"start": "source .env && node ./app.js | pino-mongodb --username=${USERNAME} --password=${PASSWORD}"
```

Comment: Thanks. How do you automatically do it? I tried `"init": "sh -ac '. .env;'", "start":
      "yarn run init &&  node ./app.js | pino-mongodb --username=${USERNAME} --password=${PASSWORD}`, it doesn't load it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "automatically". You mean in a CI configuration?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Currently all of my environment variables are in an `.env` file which I can access via `process.env` in my code after being loaded via dotenv npm package. In your answer, you set it in CLI one by one before start script.

Comment: thanks, never mind my comment, I figured it out using `better-npm-run` package which loads the .env file :) It works now.